# How to get Type II error probability from G*Power

Tags: type-i-and-ii-errors, gpower

I realize that having standard error of the mean, critical value, sample mean values from a simple a priori power test in the G*Power [free download](http://www.gpower.hhu.de/en.html), one could use NORM.DIST in Excel (Argh!) following [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFlrJDh4N9E), or calculate in R following [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7402/how-do-i-find-the-probability-of-a-type-ii-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but surely, and I realize this is daft, Type II error is simply $1 - power$? And if so, once one has calculated the actual power, one could just take it as $1 - 0.7513 = 0.2487$ (for example)? I've just started using G*Power and cannot see that shown anywhere.

Comment: Question I found interesting despite being off-topic here. Also, yes, that is what type II error is.

Comment: Yes.  Power = 1 - beta, where beta = the Type II error rate.  Thus beta = 1 - power.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're unsure? Some source or other that appears to define power differently from you & @rolando2?

Comment: Sorry, I realise it was off topic but wasn't sure where to repost. It's just that if you google 'how to calculate type II error' you get a lot of posts that go into the probability side of things whereby you do it from scratch, and I found that confusing. Just wanted to confirm that I wasn't missing some nuance.

Comment: It's not obviously off-topic, just hard to see where it's coming from without any explanation of the reasons for your doubt. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics).